# Custom Gradle plugin - sharing data beetwen plugins

Tags: gradle, kotlin, plugins

I developed a custom Gradle plugin to read some data from a file but I would like to develop the second one plugin to sending this data to the external server(plugin to sending data should depend on the plugin to reading data). I know that one Gradle plugin can detect the second plugin if there are using in the application. I don't have any idea how to pass or get data(string or dto) from one to another plugin. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin should provide the reading data logic in a form of a task: `readData`. Then the second plugin should create a task like `sendData`.

Once both tasks are created and are working independently of one another, then configure them to depend on one another:

```
tasks.named("sendData") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("readData")
}
```

In the above, in order to send data, the reading part needs to happen first.

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your DTO's and tasks etc into a "base" plugin. This plugin does not add any tasks to the model, it simply makes them available on the classpath and possibly adds a [common extension object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) to the model

Your "reader" plugin applies the "base" plugin and adds the "reader" tasks to the model

Your "publisher" plugin applies the "base" plugin and adds the "publisher" to tasks the model. These tasks will depend on any "reader" tasks in the model (eg via `tasks.withType(...)`)

Note: Gradle will only ever apply a plugin once to a project. So if "reader" and "publisher" are applied to the same project, the "base" plugin will only be applied once

Gradle uses this pattern internally. Many plugins apply the "base" plugin which adds the clean, check and assemble [lifecycle tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:lifecycle_tasks). All the java plugins apply the "java-base" plugin which adds the sourceSets to the model and also applies the "base" plugin